# WCF Transaction against Azure SQL DB

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, transactions

I am trying to make a WCF Transaction against an Azure SQL DB which is proving to be unsuccessful so far.
Here is an example:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
      try
      {
             ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
             proxy1.UpdateData();
             ServiceReference2.Service1Client proxy2 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
             proxy2.UpdateData();
             ts.Complete();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
             ts.Dispose();
      }
}
```

Where UpdateData() implementation looks like this:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public void UpdateData()
{
     SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
     objConnection.Open();
     SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO[Security].[Tenants] VALUES(3, 'test', '2016-04-14 14:20:00", objConnection);
     objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     objConnection.Close();
}
```

What happens is on connection.Open() an exception is thrown:
Object reference not set to instance of an object at at System.Transactions.Transaction.GetPromotedToken()

If I try to execute this without a transaction scope or in a transaction scope in the same service it is executed successfully. The problem occurs only if I try executing it in a WCF Transaction.

Comment: Posting the full exception would be a good idea. You should also implement using statements for both SqlConnection and SqlCommand b/c they both implement IDisposable.

Comment: This is a proof of concept test project. That's why it's missing the using clause.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that WCF transactions rely on the Distributed Transaction Coordinator which is not supported natively in Azure.

The only support for distributed transactions in SQL Azure are newer, SQL-native elastic transactions, with support introduced as part of .NET 4.6.1:

[SQL Azure elastic transactions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview/)

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Azure SQL DB V12.

Comment: Yes but WCF doesn't support propagating these new elastic transactions. It only works with older, DTC-style transactions which are not supported by SQL Azure.

Comment: Initiating the transaction outside the service boundary and flowing it across both service calls to SQL Azure... yes, currently not supported.