# Hangfire: Azure SQL: Adding a new job is failing

Tags: distributed-transactions, hangfire, azure-sql-database

Getting the below error

Inner Exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Stack Trace:
at System.Transactions.Transaction.GetPromotedToken()

The error comes from the line  connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current); in below code even if i set enlist=false in the connection string.

```
   `internal T UseTransaction<T>([InstantHandle] Func<DbConnection, DbTransaction, T> func, IsolationLevel? isolationLevel)
    {
     #if NETFULL
        using (var transaction = CreateTransaction(isolationLevel ?? _options.TransactionIsolationLevel))
        {
            var result = UseConnection(connection =>
            {
                connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
                return func(connection, null);
            });

            transaction.Complete();

            return result;
        }
}`
```

when we set enlist=true, then we get error at the line connection.Open(); from the below code

```
    internal DbConnection CreateAndOpenConnection()
    {
        if (_existingConnection != null)
        {
            return _existingConnection;
        }

        var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }
```

both the methods are present under Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage class

Same code works when connected to the local DB (SQL server 2014).

Landed on a discussion [WCF Transaction against Azure SQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648561/wcf-transaction-against-azure-sql-db), not sure if it is relevant for this issue.

**Edit:**

HangFire Configuration

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(
                Database.ConnectionString,
                new SqlServerStorageOptions
                {
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                    PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true
                });
```

Job Enqueue

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Update(connectionToken, intFileUniqueId));
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code where you add the Hanfire job?

Comment: Hi, Added HangFire configuration and job enqueue code snippets!!!

Comment: BackgroundJob.Enqueue(x => x.Update(connectionToken, intFileUniqueId)); what is x, can you also add the code which wrap than enqueue line.

Comment: It's just a Lambda expression, Enqueue function takes an "action" as parameter: var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!"));

Updated further...

Comment: Normally, when running the job, Hangfire will need to create an instance of your 'x' object then call Update of your x object with serialized values of your parameter. So the problem may comes from the type of that x. Usually what i do is to create a separate class called BackgroundProcess with a parameter less constructor, and put my background method to it.

Comment: I have done exactly same thing, that's not a problem as same code base is working for local SQL server 2014 database, the problem is appears only in case of Azure SQL database.
As I have mentioned in the problem description, I suspect it has something to do with Azure not supporting distributed transaction. But, there as well, I'm bit skeptical, as "Enqueue" works fine with some other function, but failing only for this function, and if transaction is the problem it should probably fail at the time of running job and not adding it. Confused!!!

Comment: I think you may post this as a bug in Hangfire github.

Comment: If it works locally, but not with AzureSQL, it's likely to be using a feature that Azure doesn't support. For example, AzureSQL doesn't support distributed transactions

Comment: I feel so, raised the issue in HangFire forum:
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/azure-sql-adding-a-new-job-is-failing/2844

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. call to method to queue job was inside transaction which was somehow leading to Distribution Transaction and Azure SQL doesn't support it.

Consider the code below:

```
    public override void UpdateFile(int intUniqueId)
    {
        using (var scope = GetTransactionScope(...))
        {
             QueueJob<Updater>(x => x.Update(token, intUniqueId));
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }


    private static void QueueJob<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action)
    {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(action);
    }
```

Removing the transaction scope in callee method works.
I'm checking the necessity of the transaction scope, if not required, I'll remove it.!!!